# Npm react Package Auto Delete. Notice: Deleting generated file... package.json

Tags: npm, create-react-app, npm-install, package.json, npm-update

## The React app is automatically deleted. please help

{
"name": "my-app",
"version": "0.1.0",  //this is package.json file version.
"private": true
}

> `I think this low version cause my react app delete`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1l0r.png)

I am try some Method. Such As:
npm i -g install